# calling vue function from js on change

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ckeditor, components

I'm trying to make a call from a on.("change") event to a vue method and that works fine but trying to give the received data from the change event to a Vue variable, the console log says that the variable has the new data, but it doesn't really change the variable correctly, it changes the last variable when you duplicate the components.

here is some of my code:

```
Vue.component('text-ceditor',{
props:['id'],
  data: function (){
    return {
      dataText: "this is something for example"
    }
  },
  template: '#text-ceditor',
  methods: {
    setData: function(data){
      console.log(data)
      this.dataText = data
      console.log(this.dataText)
    }
  },
  mounted: function(){
    CKEDITOR.replace(this.$refs.text);
    self = this;
    CKEDITOR.instances.texteditor.on('change', function() { 
      self.setData(this.getData())
    })
  }
})
```

the component works correctly but the variable just change the last one

here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/labradors_/3snmcu84/1/

Comment: Could you expand exactly on the bug you are trying to isolate?

Comment: when you try to write in the first or any component, just the last one get the change, and it should be handled separately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem isn't with `Vue` but with `CKEDITOR` and its instances (with the ids you defined in the template and the way you reference them).

---

First problem is that you're duplicating ids in the `text-ceditor` component:

```
<textarea ref="text" v-model="dataText" id="texteditor" rows="10" cols="80"></textarea>
```

**Why do we need to fix this?** Because `CKEDITOR` instances in Javascript are id-based.

So now we need to change the id attribute to use the one passed in the component's props, like this:

```
<textarea ref="text" v-model="dataText" :id="id" rows="10" cols="80"></textarea>
```

---

Once we took care of that, let's reference the correct `CKEDITOR` instance from within the `mounted` method in the component.

**We want to reference the one that matches with the id in our component.**

From:

```
mounted: function(){
  CKEDITOR.replace(this.$refs.text);
  self = this;
  CKEDITOR.instances.texteditor.on('change', function() { 
    self.setData(this.getData())
  })
}
```

To:

```
mounted: function () {
  CKEDITOR.replace(this.$refs.text);
  var self = this;
  var myCKEInstance = CKEDITOR.instances[self.id]
  myCKEInstance.on('change', function () {
    self.dataText = myCKEInstance.getData()
  })
}
```

*Notice that I also removed the call to `setData` as there is no need to have it and also declared `self` as a variable avoiding the global scope (which would overwrite it everytime and reference the latest one in all different components).*

---

## Now everything is updating correctly, [here's the working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3snmcu84/44/).